# C++ Encapsulation Techniques

Tags: c++, inheritance, encapsulation

I'm trying to properly encapsulate a class A, which should only be operated on by class B.

However, I want to inherit from class B.

Having A friend B doesn't work -- friendship isn't inherited.

What's the generally accepted way of accomplish what I want, or am I making a mistake?

To give you a bit more color, class A represents a complex system's state.  It should only be modified by B, which are actions that can be applied to change class A's state.

Comment: Needs more info, as from the little details you have given there doesn't seem a logical reason that the "state" of your "system" would be an "action."

Comment: Are you trying to say that B has A and when C inherits from A, C still has access to A (the member field of B)?

Comment: A think he's saying that there's one honking great A, and lots of little B's and C/D/E's which need to modify it. C/D/E all being derived classes of B.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you want to allow descendants of B to access A directly? If A and B are tightly coupled, you can make A a protected class definition within B itself, instead of being an independent definition.  E.G.

```
class B
{
protected:
    class A
    {
    };
};
```

Another idea is to create protected methods on B that delegate their actions to A.  E.G.

```
class A
{
friend class B;
private:
    void DoSomething();
};

class B
{
protected:
    void DoSomething(A& a) { a.DoSomething(); }
};
```

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you may need to do a redesign; your class A represents a State, but your Class B represents a set of actions.  There's a relationship there, but it's not an inheritance relationship.  I'd suggest composition; you want more of a HASA relationship than an ISA relationship, as far as I can tell.

Comment: Was thinking the same thing, but wasn't sure if he just wasn't giving enough info

Comment: This is especially true if Class B is going to contain multiple instances of Class A (multiple states). http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern

Comment: As I understand it, he wants A to be the system and B to be a base class from which different actions inherit, not B to inherit from A.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand you correctly, you want to have B **and it's derivatives** to have access to the internal implementation of class A, yes?

Unfortunately, C++ does not have the concept of "internal" protection levels that languages like C# and Java posses.

You can consider using the [private implementation paradigm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_pointer) (pimpl) - also known as opaque pointers, to expose functionality within your system using public access levels, that consumers of A and B would not see.

Answer (score 2):

The most straightforward way to do this is simply to have B contain an A:

class B {
protected:
  A a_;
};

Then, you can write a class C which inherits from B and is able to manipulate A. If C shouldn't be able to do arbitrary things to the A, then make the A private in B and provide protected methods in B that C can use to do approved things to the A, like so:

class B {
private:
  A a_;
protected:
  void doSomethingToA();
};

Comment: He wants to inherit from class B.

Comment: I don't like this.  It says that A (the system) is a part of B (action), i.e., the action has a system.  This makes no sense.

Comment: Hmm, Ari may be right about this, though it's difficult to tell what the OP's intent was without some clarification.

Answer (score 2):

Keeping everything as is, the easiest thing to do is to add protected methods to B that give access to the equivalent feature of A it would need.  This opens the encapsulation to just subclasses of B.

Answer (score 1):

Containment is the way to go (class B contains private member of type A) unless B needs to override some virtuals in A, in which case *private inheritance* is the closest thing.

Answer (score 0):

I cant see why you would want to inherit. Make everything in A private and friend B. B then has a member of A which it can freely manipulate.

Answer (score 0):

The way you describe this it sounds more like composition rather than inheritance. E.g.

```
class ComplexMachine {
  public:
    setState(int state);
};

class Operator {
   public:
   Operator(ComplexMachine & m) :_m(m) {};

   void drive() { _m->setState(1); }
   void turn() { _m->setState(2); }
   void stop() { _m->setState(0); }

   private:
   ComplexMachine _m;   
};

class SmoothOperator : public Operator { }
```

Answer (score 0):

Working with the bits of information you have given:

Class B should be responsible for preserving the invariants of class A, and class B should be the only way to manipulate A. Any client - derived class or caller - should not need to know that A exists.

(From design POV, there's even no *need* for A to exist, but I have encountered enough practical reasons for such a separation that I won't hold it against you ;))

This might require a lot of boilerplate code to be written, or some trickery with the interface. e.g. if client should be allowed to use class A to query information but not to modify it, B could hand out a const & to the aggregated A. With a compiler supporting __declspec(property) or similar, the syntactic pain can be eased.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand from your question, you will need some **polymorphism**. You need an **abstract** class A and class B inherits class A. Also, the **protected** keyword allows the classes that inherit to have access to certain information while at the same time deny access to anything else. Here is a little example:

```
// dynamic allocation and polymorphism
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class CPolygon {
  protected:
    int width, height;
  public:
    void set_values (int a, int b)
      { width=a; height=b; }
    virtual int area (void) =0;
    void printarea (void)
      { cout << this->area() << endl; }
  };

class CRectangle: public CPolygon {
  public:
    int area (void)
      { return (width * height); }
  };

class CTriangle: public CPolygon {
  public:
    int area (void)
      { return (width * height / 2); }
  };

int main () {
  CPolygon * ppoly1 = new CRectangle;
  CPolygon * ppoly2 = new CTriangle;
  ppoly1->set_values (4,5);
  ppoly2->set_values (4,5);
  ppoly1->printarea();
  ppoly2->printarea();
  delete ppoly1;
  delete ppoly2;
  return 0;
}
```

Code taken from [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/polymorphism/) (contains information on polymorphism and abstract classes too).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be sure that only B operates on A, make the instance of A private and expose a protected interface from B to its descendants.

```
class A
{
  public:
    void foo() {}
};

class B
{
  private:
    A a;

  protected:
    void CallAFoo() { a.foo() };
};

class C : public B
{
    void goo() { CallAFoo(); }
};
```